# Need Explanation on Pass DataKeyNames into Code Behind

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I've been struggling in half day to strive for understanding "**DatakeyNames**" obtained from listview where it passed the Entity fields value captured from "EntityDatasource" and stored into DataKeyNames for later use in Code Behind (Example: 'EntityDataSource1_Deleted' events).

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id,ImageUrl" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource2" OnItemDeleted="ListView1_ItemDeleted" >
```

-In My Code Behind,

```
protected void EntityDataSource2_Deleted(object sender, EntityDataSourceChangedEventArgs e)
{ 
    string id_ = this.ListView1.DataKeys[0]["Id"].ToString();

    string url_ = this.ListView1.DataKeys[0]["ImageUrl"].ToString();

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Notification", "alert('check ID:" + id_ + "with Url:" + url_ + "')", true);

} //End of ItemDeleted
```

**My Question Here:**

1. What is structure "**[0]**" means where it is used besides "**DataKeys**".
2. If I change "**[0]**" to be "**[1]**", it would obtained the same result as taken from "**[0]**".
3. If I change "**[0]**" with "**[this.listview1.selectedIndex]**", it will end up into unlimited looped or hanging in pages postback.Why?

Answer (score 0):

1. The structure [0] means the item at index 0

   2. The result will be different